# Passing out-of-scope variable with jest.mock

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I have a mock object that I am using to mock `react-native`:

```
const MyMock = {
    MockA: {
        methodA: jest.genMockFn()
    },
    MockB: {
        ObjectB: {
            methodA: jest.genMockFn(),
            methodB: jest.genMockFn(),
        }
    }
};


jest.mock('react-native', () => {
    return MyMock;
});
```

I am declaring the object outside of `jest.mock` because I also need it later on in my tests:

```
describe('MyClass', () => {
     beforeEach(() => {
         MyMock.MockB.ObjectB.methodA.mockClear();
         MyMock.MockB.ObjectB.methodB.mockClear();
     });
     //some other code
```

I get this error:

> The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.

The problem is that I declare `MyMock` outside of `jest.mock`. But I have no choice as far as I can see.

So how can I make the code work while keeping `MyMock` outside of `jest.mock`?

Answer (score 53):

I hadn't read the error message fully. On the last line(slightly obscured) there is this:

> Note: This is a precaution to guard against uninitialized mock variables. If it is ensured that the mock is required lazily, variable names prefixed with `mock` are permitted.

So when I changed `MyMock` to for instance `mockMyMock`, it worked.

Comment: This is very useful! Prefixing variables with `mock` reduces code duplication while maintaining clear scopes of what the mocked item should be able to access.

Comment: Appreciate the follow up comment. Any chance you happen to know where in the Jest documentation this naming convention is noted?

Comment: Not sure about the docs, but the error message I got was quite good. So for import `const {level} = require('test-utils/mocks')` and mock `jest.mock('level', () => level)` the error was: `The module factory of jest.mock() is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables. Invalid variable access: ... Whitelisted objects: ... Note: This is a precaution to guard against uninitialized mock variables. If it is ensured that the mock is required lazily, variable names prefixed with `mock` (case insensitive) are permitted.` Prefixing with `mock` didn't help though.

Comment: This worked though: `jest.mock('level', () => require('test-utils/mocks').level)`

Comment: After prepending `mock` to the function name, I am getting the error 'Cannot read `undefined` of `functionName`'. Any idea why this might be happening?